# 400 Bad Request in Rest WCF Post method?

Tags: entity-framework-4

My Code is :

```
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "InsertUser", Method = "POST")]
        public int InsertUser(Sales_Data instance)
        {
            using (DataEntities cxt = new DataEntities())
            {
                Sales_Data visitor = new Sales_Data();
                visitor.fname = instance.fname;
                visitor.email = instance.email;
                visitor.phone = instance.phone;

                cxt.AddToSales_Data(visitor);
                cxt.SaveChanges();

                return visitor.ID;
            }
        }
```

Request Input :

```
 <Sales_Data>
                        <fname>ff</fname>
                        <email>ggg</email>
                       <phone>4444</phone>
                      </Sales_Data>
```

Then while testing it in rest client i am getting 400 Bad Request.

Can you please any thing wrong in Request input .